# Multiple recordEditForm forms field value check

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I have a requirement that must replace the functionality of a third-party software in which a list of opportunity team member roles must all be assigned in a single screen. To accomplish this, I have built a lightning component with multiple lightning:recordEditForm elements.  Each has its own (hidden) role name, along with the user assigned and a user profile photo (if available).  This is all working fine.

However, I do not want separate submit buttons under each form, so I am trying to use Javascript to check the "UserId" field on each form to see if there is an entry, then submit the ones with an entry (thus only creating the assigned opportunity team members).  The problem is that I don't know how to drill down into the form object to see if there is an entry for the UserId.  This is where I need help.

I'm stuck creating this last little if() condition...

```
saveTeam: function (cmp, event, helper) {
    var forms = cmp.find('tmForm');
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
        // If the form has a UserId entry, submit
        if (true) forms[i].submit();
    }
}
```

This does try to submit each form - and of course, it sets a "missing input" flag/error on each form.  I just need to replace that "true" condition with one that actually checks the UserId.

So how do I get the UserId field within the forms[i] object so I can check UserId ***before*** I submit?

Comment: How are the user ids declared in the forms? If you have unique attributes say `UserId1`, `UserId2` and so on defined for your forms, you can fetch it using `cmp.get(“v.UserId(x)”)` and validate it accordingly.

Comment: Valid answer but...I was looking for a more elegant solution.  I may end up having to ID each one and write handlers for each if I don't get a better solution here.